# Константы для максимальных значений

Tags: c++, limits

Какая константа в STD определяет максимальное значение для типа `std::uint64_t` и для других подобных типов? Или использовать хедер `<climits>` ?

Comment: У вас там экзамен что ли?

Comment: Проще всего посмотреть /usr/include/limits.h

Comment: @alexout Нет, тут просто shared-аккаунт. Пока один коллега ужинает, другой пользуется возможностью.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, если по-хорошему - то я бы делал через `std::numeric_limits<>::max()`.